# PATH specification when using the R package gdata

Tags: perl, r, xls

Problem: helpers fail when reading an .xls into R using gdata

I have some .xls that i'd like to read into R.  I am able to do so using `read.xls` in the `gdata` package, however the helper functions `sheetNames` and `sheetCount` fail - i'd like to understand what i'm doing wrong so that i can use them as they would be very useful.

```
require(gdata)
fp <- file.path('~/data/first.xls')
```

When i know the structure of the sheets, and am able to point it at my intended data sheet, the perl script runs just fine:

```
firstdata <- read.xls(fp, sheet=2)
```

and i have my data... in `firstdata`.

However, in the very same sheets, the helpers fail.

I find myself opening the .xls in excel, figuring them out, and then loading into R using `read.xls(fp, sheet=N)` -- not a disaster, but neither is it ideal.

In particular, when the sheets are not my own, and I need information about them before i can set `sheet=N` in `read.xls()`, the helper functions `sheetNames` and `sheetCount` would be very useful, however they fail -- why?

```
sheetCount(fp)

> sheetNames(fp)
Error in read.table(tc, as.is = TRUE, header = FALSE) : 
  no lines available in input
In addition: Warning message:
running command ''/usr/bin/perl'     '~/R/wd/raRpackages/gdata/perl/sheetNames.pl' '~/data/first.xls'' had status 2 
Unable to open file '~/data/first.xls'.
```

and:

```
> sheetCount(fp)
Error in read.table(tc, as.is = TRUE, header = FALSE) :  
  no lines available in input
In addition: Warning message:
running command ''/usr/bin/perl'     '~/R/wd/raRpackages/gdata/perl/sheetCount.pl' '~/data/first.xls'' had status 2 
Unable to open file '~/data/first.xls'.
```

After a bit of fiddling, i (quite by accident) found that using the full path solves this problem:

```
fp2 <- file.path("/Users/ricardo/data/first.xls")
sheetcount(fp2)
[1] 13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `~` isn't being expanded out to your home directory. This expansion is usually done by the shell so R probably won't do it and perl definitely won't.

Instead, use the explicit path or `$HOME` or `$ENV{HOME}` from within the Perl program.

Comment: +1 thanks. that does fix the problem. as a general rule should one prefer the explicit paths to avoid these traps?